# How can a recursive regexp be implemented in python?

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I'm interested how can be implemented recursive regexp matching in Python (I've not found any examples :( ). For example how would one write expression which matches "bracket balanced" string like "foo(bar(bar(foo)))(foo1)bar1"

Comment: @Tempus, indeed, or Tony will come. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/193892

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant it's ok, I know Tony. He's a friend.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyparsing import nestedExpr
import sys
astring=sys.argv[1]
if not astring.startswith('('):
    astring='('+astring+')'

expr = nestedExpr('(', ')')
result=expr.parseString(astring).asList()[0]
print(result)
```

Running it yields:

```
% test.py "foo(bar(bar(foo)))(foo1)bar1"
['foo', ['bar', ['bar', ['foo']]], ['foo1'], 'bar1']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with a regexp. Python doesn't support recursive regexp

Answer (score 2):

With PyPi regex, that you can easily install using `pip install regex`, you may use

```
import regex

pattern = r'[^()]*+(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\)[^()]*+)++'
text = 'foo(bar(bar(foo)))(foo1)bar1'
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(pattern, text)))
# => True
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/JMJ49636), see the [regex pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/00NSaa/1) (note the `\A` and `\z` anchors are added in the demo because `regex.fullmatch` requires a full string match).

**Pattern details**

- `\A` - implicit in `regex.fullmatch` - start of string
- `[^()]*+` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` (possessive match, no backtracking into the pattern allowed)
- `(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\)[^()]*+)++` - 1+ occurrences of Group 1 pattern:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?>[^()]|(?1))*+` - 1+ repetitions (possessive match)  of

    - `[^()]` - any char but `(` and `)`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - a regex subroutine that recurses Group 1 pattern
  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `[^()]*+` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` (possessive match)
- `\z` - implicit in `regex.fullmatch` - end of string.

See the [pattern and more information on regex subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) at regular-expressions.info.