# Regex to find function call php

Tags: php, regex

I need the regex to find function calls in strings in php, I have tried to search here on stackoverflow but none of the ones i've tried worked.

this pattern: `^.*([\w][\(].*[\)])`

This will match: `functionone(fgfg)` but also `functionone(fgfg) dhgfghfgh functiontwo()` as one match. Not 2 separate matches (as in `functionone(fgfg)` and `functiontwo()`.

I don't know how to write it but I think this is what I need.
1. Any string, followed by **(**
2. Any string followed by **)**

And then it should stop, not continue. Any regex-gurus that can help me out?

Comment: Instead of .* which is greedy operator, try using .*?, which is lazy.

Comment: see here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php

Comment: Have fun with $x = functionOne(functionTwo("fgfg")); and all the myriad of similar permutations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 5 issues with your regex

1. If you want to match 2 functions in the same row, don't use the anchor `^`, this will anchor the regex to the start of the string.
2. You then don't need `.*` at the start maybe more something like `\w+` (I am not sure what the spec of a function name in PHP is)
3. if there is only one entry in a character class (and its not a negated one), you don't need the character class
4. The quantifier between the brackets needs to be a lazy one (followed by a `?`). So after this 4 points your regex would look something like

   ```
   \w+\(.*?\)
   ```
5. **Is a regex really the right tool for this job?**

Comment: This actually worked, big thank you! But you are all right. Tokenizer would be a better alternative but it didn't find my functions as functions, but as html.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regexp for this... use PHP's built-in [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php)

Answer (score 1):

A function signature is not a regular language. As such, you cannot use a regular expression to match a function signature. Your current regex will match signatures that are NOT valid function signatures.

What I would suggest you use is the PHP tokenizer.

Comment: Valid point, invalid argument, [PCRE is not regular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434272/match-an-bn-cn-e-g-aaabbbccc-using-regular-expressions-pcre).