# RegEx with JavaScript matches more that it should

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

Fairly simple HTML (the ellipses indicate that there's more code):

```
...Profile">
 Some text
 </a>...
```

Using on-line RegEx tester for JavaScript (http://regexpal.com/), I can extract "Some text" (note that it contains newlines) with the following expression:

```
(?=Profile">)[\s\S]*(?=</a)
```

(Unfortunately, look-behinds are not supported by JavaScript, and so I also extract Something"> to later remove this. The problem is, however, that the below code

```
var ShowContent = document.getElementById(id);
ShowContent = ShowContent.innerHTML;
var patt3=/Profile">[\s\S]*(?=<)/;
var GetName=patt3.exec(ShowContent);
alert(GetName);
```

doesn't extract what the on-line tester shows, but also it includes the whole HTML code that is after "Some text" (IE, not only the ending `< /a` but also everything after).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008839/why-use-dom-to-parse-webpages-instead-of-regex

Comment: *Does anyone has any suggestions?* - Yes. Not using regex to parse HTML would be a pretty good start.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely learn DOM in the future, but I now need a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're certain that the supplied string does not contain possible pitfalls (eg. `<input value='Profile">'>`, replace `[\s\S]*` with `[^<]*` (anything but a `<`):

```
var patt3 = /Profile">([^<]*)/;
var getName = patt3.exec(ShowContent);
getName = getName ? getName[1] : ''; // If no match has been found -> empty string

alert(getName);
```

(I also replaced `GetName` with `getName`, because camelCased variables starting with a capital usually indicate a constructor. Stick to the conventions, and do not start non-constructors with a capital).

Comment: What's the point in using regex when there *alredy is* a DOM (for free!) that you can use to extract a node's value?

Comment: @Tomalak The question did not include enough information to post an answer regarding DOM traversal. It did, however, contain clear conditions for finding the text.

Comment: @Rob W Thank you so much! Yes, I will use this as a temporary solution, but will spend time to learn DOM for later updates of my home code.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That would call for some clarification. It can't be difficult to do, though. Looks like the text of a single certain link should be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off making the quantifier ungreedy. Try this regex:

```
/Profile">([\s\S]*?)(?=<)/
```