# Match substrings of same length using regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have a challenge similar to finding "matching brackets", but I suppose this is a simpler one.
For instance, string like "xAAAyBBBz" should match, as there are 3 A's and 3 B's. However, "xAAyBBBz" should not match, as there is one "unmatched" B. Strings have arbitrary length, and it is supposed to be one single regexp. I could use in-regexp evaluation (it is Perl after all) and I could (should!) avoid regexp at all. But now I got curious.

Comment: What if x, y, or z contain A or B?

Comment: The pattern you describe is not matchable by traditional regular expressions, as the pattern is not a regular language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). It may be matchable via extensions, however.

Comment: I believe that [this previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434272/match-an-bn-cn-e-g-aaabbbccc-using-regular-expressions-pcre) answers your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^AB]*(A(?:[^AB]*|(?-1))B)[^AB]*\z
```

```
^
[^AB]*       # "x"
(
  A
  (?:
    [^AB]*   # "y"
  |
    (?-1)
  )
  B
)
[^AB]*       # "z"
\z
```

The capturing group `(A(?:[^AB]*|(?-1))B)` matches an `A` at the beginning and a `B` at the end. In between, there may be either any number of non-(`A` or `B`) characters, or the pattern of the first capture group may match recursively at this position (`(?-1)`). This guarantees that the `A`s and `B`s are balanced.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your regex too.

Comment: This works if the As and Bs are consecutive, but I'm not sure that's always the case. If they don't have to be, simply extend the parens to include both outer "`[^AB]*`".

Comment: @melpomene Answers should as a general rule come with explanations. Even though something might seem obvious to you, it may not be to others.

Comment: @ikegami "*I have a challenge similar to finding "matching brackets", but I suppose this is a simpler one.*" If the A/B's don't have to be consecutive, it is exactly the matching brackets problem.

Comment: @TLP That's why I was asking which parts were non-obvious. When I write a solution in, say, C, I don't annotate each line a la `int i; // declares an integer variable` because I assume the asker already knows C. Similarly, for regex questions I assume the asker knows regexes.

Comment: I know that's why you asked. My previous comment still stands.

Comment: @TLP If you already knew, why comment? My previous question still stands.

Comment: @melpomene I would have thought that would be obvious. I made the comment because your answer lacked an explanation. It was a suggestion on how you could improve your answer. This is a learning environment, people come here to learn new things, that is why explanations are important.

Comment: @TLP I still don't know what exactly I'm supposed to explain.

Comment: Oh, I think you do. And if not, it will be easier for you to figure out than it would be for a novice to decipher your regex.

Comment: @melpomene: kudos for the great tip, however, I'd recommend you to point out that `(?-1)` is the *prestige* part of your magic ;) @amon: thanks for providing the explanation!