# "Untranslatable" Grammars to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, grammar, context-free-grammar, automata

Are there such things?

Like for example, S -> aSb | ^ (possible words: ^, ab, aabb, aaabbb, aaaabbbb, ...)

From what I've learned, the only regex that closely match the said grammar is: a*b*

But the regex can produce words such as aab, abb, ... where a's and b's aren't equal.

Is there a solution to this? Something like: a*b* if #a = #b

EDIT: I think there is no solution to this.

What is the correct explanation for this? This is actually a snippet of my homework, and I really don't know what to answer since there are no solutions in translating the grammar to regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about formal language theory then of course all non-regular grammars (as in your example) can't be expressed with a regular expression (per definition).

But if you are wondering of what different regex flavors (in programming languages/regex libs) can do, then you can match all kinds of non-regular grammars/languages.

For example in Perl/PCRE you can match your example language with any of these:

- Using recursion/sub pattern calls:

  `^(a(?1)b)$`
- Using a backreference (with a conditional):

  `^(?:a(?=a*(b(?(1)\1))))+\1$|^$`

You may be interested in this questions and answers: [Match a^n b^n c^n (e.g. "aaabbbccc") using regular expressions (PCRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434272)

Comment: The question is actually related to our class, and I don't know if we can use symbols that are used in PCRE. The only symbols we used were * and + (kleene star and plus).

Comment: I really think that it cannot be translated into a regex. I now wonder what to answer in my homework.

Comment: @user1846682, your homework appears to be in formal language theory. In which case the first sentence of the answer applies. That is no, you can't make a formal regex for a non-regular language.

Comment: `^(?:a(?=a*(b\1?)))*\1$|^$` also works in .NET, but not in JS. It seems that the backreference is used to match the previous capture in the repetition (and not all regex engine supports this)?

Comment: @nhahtdh, works in Java too. Didn't know about JS (altho wouldn't expect much there). In JS it seems that the backref doesn't get redefined after the first capture.

Answer (score 0):

In formal language theory something called a "pumping lemma" can be used to prove that certain sets of sentences (languages) can not be described by a regular expression. See wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages. You start from the language you want to describe and use the pumping lemma to find a contradiction. The proof for your example is actually on that wikipedia page.

A similar theory exists for context-free languages. Some languages just can not be described by context-free grammars.