# How to remove backpath/parentpath from the URL?

Tags: php, regex

Input:

```
http://foo/bar/baz/../../qux/
```

Desired Output:

```
http://foo/qux/
```

This can be achieved using regular expression (unless someone can suggest a more efficient alternative).

If it was a forward look-up, it would be as simple as:

```
/\.\.\/[^\/]+/
```

Though I am not familiar with with how to make a backward look up for the first "/" (ie. not doing `/[a-z0-9-_]+\/\.\./`).

One of the solutions I thought of is to use `strrev` then apply forward look up regex (first example) and then do `strrev`. Though I am sure there is a more efficient way.

Comment: note that /[^\/]+/ matches /../

Comment: @Qsebas that is true - if it can be assumed that the input is properly formatted, that won't be an issue, but true...

Answer (score 0):

Not the clearest question I've ever seen, but if I understand what you're asking, I think you only need to switch around what you have like this:

```
/[^\/]+/\.\./
```

...then replace that with a `/`

Do that until no replacements are made and you should have what you want

**EDIT**

Your attempt seems to try to match a forward slash `/` and two dots `\.\.` followed by a slash `/` (or `\/` - they should both match the same thing), then one or more non-slash characters`[^/]+`, terminated by a slash `/`. Flipping it around, you want to find a slash followed by one or more non-slash characters and a terminating slash, then two dots and a final slash.

You may be confused into thinking that the regex engine parses and consumes things as it goes (so you wouldn't want to consume a directory name that is not followed by the correct number of dots), but that's not how it typically works - a regex engine matches the *entire* expression before it replaces or returns anything. So, you can have two dots followed by a directory name, or a directory name followed by two dots - it doesn't make a difference to the engine.

If your attempt is using the slash-enclosed Perl-style syntax, then you would of course need to use `\/` for any slashes you're trying to match such as the middle one, but I would also recommend matching and replacing the enclosing slashes in the url as well: I think the PHP would be something like

```
preg_replace('/\/[^\/]+\/\.\.\//', '/', $input)
```

(??)

Comment: Doesn't work on any legal path without trailing slash: `/aaa/bbb/ccc/..`. Doesn't work on path like this: `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/../../../../`

Answer (score 0):

Technically what do you want is replace segments of '/path1/path2/../../' by '/' what is needed to do that is match 'pathx/'^n'../'^n  that is definetly NOT a regular expression (Context Free Lenguaje) ... but most of Regex libraries supports some non regular lenguajes and can (with a lot of effort) manage those kind of lenguajes.

An easy way to solve it is stay in Regular Expressions and cycle several times, replacing '/[^./]+/../' by ''

if you still to do it in a single step, Lookahead and grouping is needed, but it will be hard to write it, (I'm not so used on, but I will try)

EDIT:

I've found the solution in only 1 REGEX... but should use PCRE Regex

```
([^/.]+/(?1)?\.\./)
```

I've based my solution on the folowing link:
[Match a^n b^n c^n (e.g. "aaabbbccc") using regular expressions (PCRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434272/match-an-bn-cn-e-g-aaabbbccc-using-regular-expressions-pcre)

(note that dots are "forbidden" in the first section, you cannot have path.1/path.2/ if you whant to is quite more complex because you should admit them but forbid '../' as valid in the first section

this sub expression is for admiting the path names like 'path1/'

```
[^/.]+/
```

this sub expression is for admiting the double dots.

```
\.\./
```

you can test the regexp in
https://www.debuggex.com/
(remember to set it in PCRE mode)

Here is a working copy:
https://eval.in/52675

Comment: Doesn't work on any legal path without trailing slash: `/aaa/bbb/ccc/..`. Doesn't work on path like this: `/aaa/bbb/..ccc/../`