# Regex to find if there is only one block of code

Tags: javascript, regex

My input is a string, I want to validate that there is only one *first-level* block of code.

Examples :

```
{ abc }              TRUE
{ a { bc } }         TRUE
{ a {{}} }           TRUE
{ abc {efg}{hij}}    TRUE
{ a b cde }{aa}      FALSE
```

`/^\{.*\}$/` is valid for the 5 cases, can you help me to find a regex invalid for the last case ?

Language is JavaScript.

Comment: What regex flavor, or what language?

Comment: Use a lookahead instead of looking at the end of the string `(?={)`. If the lookahead evaluates to true, then your regex doesn't match.

Comment: Traditionally regular expressions can't handle nested constructs. Modern regular expressions parsers are better, but handling nested constructs is still not perfect.

Comment: Is there a valid(TRUE) situation where "}{" can exist?

Comment: @dwana, yes, `{abc{def}{hij}}` is valid.

Comment: there is always the option, DIY

Comment: Can you use anything else?  Something like a small state machine would be easier to do and probably clearer

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I started writing the answer before JavaScript was specified. Will leave it as for the record as it fully explains the regex.

**In short:** In JavaScript I cannot think of a reliable solution. In other engines there are several options:

- Recursion (on which I will expand below)
- Balancing group (.NET)

For solutions 2 (which anyhow won't work in JS either), I'll refer you to the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23728051/1078583)

### Recursive Regex

In Perl, PCRE (e.g. Notepad++, PHP, R) and the Matthew Barnett's `regex` module for Python, you can use:

```
^({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})$
```

The idea is to match exactly one set of nested braces. Anything more makes the regex fail.

See what matches and fails in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/14)**.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The outer parentheses define Group 1 (or Subroutine 1)
- `{` match the opening brace
- `(?: ...  )*` zero or more times, we will...
- `[^{}]++` match any chars that are not `{` or `}`
- OR `|`
- `(?1)` repeat the expression of subroutine 1
- `}` match closing brace
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string. Therefore,

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has specified now that they're looking for javascript and this solution is invalid in javascript. +1 for the recursive regex demo, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a terrible workaround.

Since this is in Javascript there's not really much to do, but please see the following regex:

```
/^{([^{}]*|{})*}$/
```

Where you copy `([^{}]*|{})*` and insert it between the last pair of curly brackets (rinse and repeat). Every duplication of this pattern allows another level of nesting between your elements. (This is a workaround for the lack of recursion in JS regex, required to solve nesting problems.)

[<kbd>Online Regex Demo</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/17)

Comment: Very practical, +1 for copy-paste regex, that would probably work in realistic cases where nesting is limited. :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript what you need to do is strip out all the nested blocks until no *nested* blocks are left and then check whether there are still multiple blocks:

```
var r = input.replace(/(['"])(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*\1|\/(?![*/])(?:[^\\/]|\\.)+\/[igm]*|\/\/[^\n]*(?:\n|$)|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\//gi, '');

if (r.split('{').length != r.split('}').length || r.indexOf('}') < r.indexOf('{')) {
    // ERROR
    continue;
}

while (r.match(/\{[^}]*\{[^{}]*\}/))
    r = r.replace(/(\{[^}]*)\{[^{}]*\}/g, '$1');
if (r.match(/\}.*\{/)
    // FALSE
else
    // TRUE
```

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvo3h1xp/2/)**

Be sure to make the regex in the `while` and the regex in the `replace` match the same otherwise this might result in infinite loops.

***Updated*** to address ERROR cases and remove anything in comments, strings and regex-literals first after Unihedron asked.

Comment: Would return TRUE, but it's an "improper" code block. If you wanna check for unmatched open curly braces that's a different problem, though related indeed. But then you'd want to consider stuff like `{ print "Went there {" } /* } { Dang edge cases! } */`. I wrote about scenarios like that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc

Answer (score -1):

```
(\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*
```

Code for brackets

Comment: No explanation, long repetitive regex dealing with regular rather than curly brackets.

Comment: It's for validation brackets ()()- valid ())- invalid ()()())-invalid