# Check if code blocks are nested correctly in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, matching, regex-negation

How to validate if code blocks, as in a construct:

```
{
    // Any amount of characters that aren't '{' or '}'
}
```

Are properly nested, preferably with regex?

```
{} {
    {} {}
} // Properly nested
```

```
{{
    {{}}
} {} // Not properly nested
```

[As referred to from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24955473/3622940), approaches such as recursion and balancing groups cannot apply here, as the [regular expression constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940) are not present in [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions for this sort of problem. I'd likely use a stack.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The user input is a `String`. Is there a way to use a stack in this situation?

Comment: Yes. I'm no expert in this, but aren't there parsers already in existence for just this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do this with regex? I suggest building your own parser. Something like this:

```
public static boolean isProperlyNested(String toTest) {
    int countOpen = 0;
    for (char c : toTest.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '{') {
            countOpen++;
        } else if (c == '}') {
            countOpen--;
            if (countOpen < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return countOpen == 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a simplification. For example what to do with a piece of code where an open or close brace is hidden in a comment; that is BTW where a stack or a state machine comes in.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The stack doesn't really work any better. Just include some booleans that toggle for comments/strings/chars/etc, and don't change the count if one of them is true.

Comment: A stack is probably overkill for this specific example (but what if I want to track balanced braces **and** parentheses), although I'd sooner opt for a enum than a set of booleans to track the current state of the parser (and I actually did just that for Jaybird; it allows for leaving the state switch to the state itself: http://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/code/HEAD/tree/client-java/trunk/src/main/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/escape/FBEscapedParser.java#l364 ).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that's true; a stack to store the character would be a good idea for testing with multiple types of matching characters.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this using two steps with a loop:

```
{
    String str1 = "{} {\n" +
                  "    {} {}\n" +
                  "} // Properly nested",
           str2 = "{{\n" +
                  "    {{}}\n" +
                  "} {} // Not properly nested";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\Q{}\\E");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1.replaceAll("[^{}]", ""));
    while (matcher.find())
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str1 = matcher.replaceAll(""));
    System.out.println(str1.isEmpty());

    matcher = pattern.matcher(str2.replaceAll("[^{}]", ""));
    while (matcher.find())
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str2 = matcher.replaceAll(""));
    System.out.println(str2.isEmpty());
}
```

[Here is an online code demo](http://ideone.com/sIQLbn). <sup>Demo is slightly different from the code I wrote here so as to show to original string orientation as well.</sup>