# Get Outer "Pair" when Nested

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the regex `<@(.+?)@>` to match patterns such as:

```
<@set:template default.spt @>
```

It works fine, but I've run into situations where I needed to nest the pattern, such as this:

```
<@set:template <@get:oldtemplate @> @>
```

Instead of getting the parent pair (<@ and @>) I get the following:

```
<@set:template <@get:oldtemplate @>
```

I don't want it to get the child one, I just want the outermost parent in all nested situations.  How to I fix my regex so that it will do this for me?  I figure I could do it if I knew how to require for every `<@` that there was one `@>` inside of the parent, but I have no idea on how to enforce that.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Python

Comment: You need `regex` package to do this. The default `re` package cannot handle arbitrary nesting level.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656859/how-can-a-recursive-regexp-be-implemented-in-python) should solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is a "non-regular language". It cannot be parsed with a regexp.

Ok, if you are willing to put a limit to the nesting level, technically you *can* do it with a regexp. But it will be ugly.

Here is how to parse your thing with a few (increasing) maximum nesting depths, if you can put the condition of not having @'s inside your tags:

```
no nesting: <@[^@]+@>
up to 1:    <@[^@]+(<@[^@]+@>)?[^@]*@>
up to 2:    <@[^@]+(<@[^@]+(<@[^@]+@>)?[^@]*@>)?[^@]*@>
up to 3:    <@[^@]+(<@[^@]+(<@[^@]+(<@[^@]+@>)?[^@]*@>)?[^@]*@>)?[^@]*@>
...
```

If you cannot forbid lone @'s in your tags, you will have to replace every instance of `[^@]` with something like this: `(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])`.

Just think about that and then think about extending your regex to parse up to 10 depth nesting.

Here, I will do it for you:

```
<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[
^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<
[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@
[^>])+(<@(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])+@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>]
)*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@
>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?
(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>)?(?:[^<@]|<[^@]|@[^>])*@>
```

What I hope my answer shows is that ***regexp are not the right tool to parse a language.*** A traditional lexer (tokenizer) and parser combination will do a much better job, be significantly faster, and will handle indefinite nesting.

Comment: It is possible to allow `@` and `>` while not consuming the end tag with `(?:(?!@>).)*`. Gotta love the end result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a Regular Expression, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets) which asks a similar thing. Regexes aren't sufficiently powerful to deal with arbitrary levels of nesting, if you will only ever have 2 levels of nesting then it should be possible, but maybe regexes aren't the best tool for the job.