# Removing data between double squiggly brackets with nested sub brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm having some difficulty with this problem.  I need to remove all data that's contained in squiggly brackets.

Like such:

```
Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there.
```

Becomes:

```
Hello there.
```

Here's my first try (I know it's terrible):

```
while 1:
    firstStartBracket = text.find('{{')
    if (firstStartBracket == -1):
        break;
    firstEndBracket = text.find('}}')
    if (firstEndBracket == -1):
        break;
    secondStartBracket = text.find('{{',firstStartBracket+2);
    lastEndBracket = firstEndBracket;
    if (secondStartBracket == -1 or secondStartBracket > firstEndBracket):
        text = text[:firstStartBracket] + text[lastEndBracket+2:];
        continue;
    innerBrackets = 2;
    position = secondStartBracket;
    while innerBrackets:
        print innerBrackets;
        #everytime we find a next start bracket before the ending add 1 to inner brackets else remove 1
        nextEndBracket = text.find('}}',position+2);
        nextStartBracket = text.find('{{',position+2);
        if (nextStartBracket != -1 and nextStartBracket < nextEndBracket):
            innerBrackets += 1;
            position = nextStartBracket;
            # print text[position-2:position+4];
        else:
            innerBrackets -= 1;
            position = nextEndBracket;
            # print text[position-2:position+4];
            # print nextStartBracket
            # print lastEndBracket
            lastEndBracket = nextEndBracket;
        print 'pos',position;
    text = text[:firstStartBracket] + text[lastEndBracket+2:];
```

It seems to work but runs out of memory quite fast.  Is there any better way to do this (hopefully with regex)?

EDIT: I was not clear so I'll give another example.  I need to allow for multiple top level brackets.

Like such:

```
Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there {{my }} friend.
```

Becomes:

```
Hello there friend.
```

Comment: so basically you wanna delete all things inside {}, right?

Comment: However as a point , if you dont want use `regex` use stack for count number of open brackets and close ones , it's more easier than sample code here.

Comment: @GLHF no it has to be inside {{ }} and not just { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a regex/generator based solution that works with any number of braces. This problem does not need an actual stack because there is only 1 type (well, pair) of token involved. The `level` fills the role that a stack would fill in a more complex parser.

```
import re

def _parts_outside_braces(text):
    level = 0
    for part in re.split(r'(\{\{|\}\})', text):
        if part == '{{':
            level += 1
        elif part == '}}':
            level = level - 1 if level else 0
        elif level == 0:
            yield part

x = 'Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there.  {{ second set {{ of }} braces }}'
print(''.join(_parts_outside_braces(x)))
```

More general points... the capture group in the regex is what makes the braces show up in the output of `re.split`, otherwise you only get the stuff in between. There's also some support for mismatched braces. For  a strict parser, that should raise an exception, as should running off the end of the string with level > 0. For a loose, web-browser style parser, maybe you would want to display those `}}` as output...

Comment: This is actually the fastest solution so far. ~ 15 µs

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pyparsing` module](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) here. Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657068/771848):

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr


s = "Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there {{my }} friend."

expr = nestedExpr('{{', '}}')
result = expr.parseString("{{" + s + "}}").asList()[0]
print(" ".join(item for item in result if not isinstance(item, list)))
```

Prints:

```
Hello there friend.
```

---

*The following would only work if there is only one top-level pair of braces.*

If you want to remove everything inside the double curly braces with the braces themselves:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = "Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there."
>>> re.sub(r"\{\{.*\}\} ", "", s)
'Hello there.'
```

`\{\{.*\}\}` would match double curly braces followed by any characters any number of times (intentionally left it ["greedy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)) followed by double curly braces and a space.

Comment: Only works if you assume there cannot be more than one top level pair of braces.

Comment: @alecxe I'm sorry I wasn't clear with my original question.

Comment: `while '{{' in s and '}}' in s` will take care of @JasonS's concern, though it will be screwed by `'}}{{'`...

Comment: @thewormsterror sure, no problem, updated with an alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import re

s = 'Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there'
m = re.search('(.*?) {.*}(.*)',s)
result = m.group(1) + m.group(2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Only works if you assume there cannot be more than one top level pair of braces.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you would have to deal with nested structure, which means regular expression may not suffice. However, a simple parser with a memory of depth level may come to rescue - it is very simple to write, just store the
depth level into a variable.

I just post a more pythonic way of writing the solution here, which may be a good reference for you.

```
import re

def rem_bra(inp):
    i = 0
    lvl = 0
    chars = []
    while i < len(inp):
        if inp[i:i+2] == '{{':
            lvl += 1
            i += 1
        elif inp[i:i+2] == '}}':
            lvl -= 1
            i += 1
        else:
            if lvl < 1:
                chars.append(inp[i])
        i += 1
    result = ''.join(chars)

    # If you need no more contigious spaces, add this line:
    result = re.sub(r'\s\s+', r' ', result)

    return result


inp = "Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there."

print(rem_bra(inp))
>>> Hello there.
```

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, yet another solution. It starts by finding and replacing the leftmost innermost braces and works its way outwards, rightwards. Takes care of multiple top level braces.

```
import re

def remove_braces(s):
    pattern = r'\{\{(?:[^{]|\{[^{])*?\}\}'
    while re.search(pattern, s):
        s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
    return s
```

Not the most efficient, but short.

```
>>> remove_braces('Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there {{my }} friend.')
'Hello  there  friend.'
```

Comment: are you kidding ? Yours is highly efficient. Takes about 90 ns for one loop compared to 10 - 25 microseconds for most other solutions.

Comment: @Moritz I guessed so :) It does search/match the string multiple times, while Jason S's solution, say, does it only once. But I like it short.

Comment: It takes 90ns to compile your function

Comment: @Moritz have you figured out what solution was the fastest between all answers?

Comment: Jasons answer is. about 15 µs. Mine is about 25 µs. Probably because i do have to convert the iterable to a list

Answer (score 1):

This question makes fun. Here is my attempt:

```
import re

def find_str(string):

    flag = 0

    for index,item in enumerate(string):

        if item == '{':
            flag += 1

        if item == '}':
            flag -= 1

        if flag == 0:
            yield index

s = 'Hello {{world of the {{ crazy}} {{need {{ be}}}} sea }} there {{my }} friend.'

index = list(find_str(s))

l = [s[i] for i in index]

s = ' '.join(l)

re.sub('}\s+','',s)
```

`'H e l l o   t h e r e   f r i e n d .'`

Answer (score 0):

With [PyPI regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) eg like this:

```
p = r'{{(?>[^}{]+|(?0))*}} ?'
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iT5vT7/2) or [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##NY1BDgIhDEX3nKI7QCfGxLWy9Q5GE8apziQIpGB0RM6O1cRu@vrz2sY5j8FvWptuMVAGwis@wSYGIVIm2ILco3MBSnkEcgOEC@QReYQz2ddcK6NHHL5Jj5ULElrgxhrhSgoR@QrJUpTZHU61HJdvZdZaL9gx8v@G1XTvVexAyg4407xIk8/qx619AA).

```
import regex as re

str = re.sub(p, '', str)
```

fyi: [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses/35271017#35271017)